# mocking dataservice with bard js

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, sinon, chai, bardjs

I'm writing an angular controller, which has a depenedency on a dataservice (data service goes to http server), and I would like to mock its behavior.

I'm mocking with a library called bard js, and it has an api to mock services called **bard.mockService**.

In the beforeEach statement I'm doing:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    bard.appModule('app.process.creation');
    bard.inject('$controller', '$rootScope', '$q', 'processCreationDataservice');

    bard.mockService(processCreationDataservice, {
        createProcess: $q.when({}),
        _default: $q.when([])
    });

    controller = $controller('ProcessCreationController');
    $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

then my test:

```
it('should call create process data service to create process', function() {
    controller.create();
    expect(processCreationDataservice.createProcess).to.have.been.calledOnce;
});
```

As you can see in the test I want to assert that dataservice.createProcess is being called once.

The controller is not calling the method processCreationDataservice.createProcess, and still the test is passing.

```
(function() {
angular
    .module('app.process.creation')
    .controller('ProcessCreationController', ProcessCreationController);

ProcessCreationController.$inject = ['processCreationDataservice'];

function ProcessCreationController(processCreationDataservice) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.process = {
        name: '',
        bankId: ''
    };

    vm.create = function() {

    };
}})();
```

I would like to know why this test is passing, and what should I do to assert that the method is being called once.

I followed these instructions:
https://github.com/wardbell/bardjs#mockService

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you neglected to load the *sinon-chai* script. You can quickly find out by pasting the following in your *specs.html* just below where you load *sinon.js*

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/domenic/sinon-chai/master/lib/sinon-chai.js"></script>
```

> I typically pull down *sinon-chai* via npm
>
> ```
> npm install sinon-chai --save-dev
> ```
>
> and then my script becomes ...
>
> ```
> <script src="/node_modules/sinon-chai/lib/sinon-chai.js"></script>
> ```

I'll bet your test fails, exactly as you would expect.

The omission of *sinon-chai* leads to a **very subtle** false positive. Follow me as as I explain:

Let's look at the assertion/expectation just before you say "calledOnce":

```
expect(processCreationDataservice.createProcess).to.have.been; // Assertion
```

It returns a chai `Assertion`. But that `Assertion` object **lacks all of the sinon assertion methods** such as `calledOnce`. The *sinon-chai* library extends *chai* with the sinon assertion methods.

So when you tack `calledOnce` to the end, you get:

```
expect(processCreationDataservice.createProcess).to.have.been.calledOnce; // undefined
```

Yup, the statement returns `undefined` ... which is an inert statement of no consequence to mocha. It's not an error. It's just a no-op.  So the `expect` does nothing and mocha thinks the test passed.

You might as well have done this (it passes too):

```
expect(processCreationDataservice.foo /*undefined*/).to.have.been.calledOnce; // undefined
```

You ***don't have to use "sinon-chai"***. It's a convenience. But if you leave it out, you'll have to write the expectation this way:

```
  // without "sinon-chai"
  expect(dataservice.createThing.calledOnce).to.be.true;
```

I created [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kdOulY?p=info) for you (and others) to explore these dynamics.

Comment: Yes, it was that. Didn't notice the script was not being loaded. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ward in the case that you want to load a module as a dependency ex:           bard.appModule('coreModule', ['utilityModule'])  do you have to identify the dependency as its own module before hand?  Or make any additional references to it?

Answer (score -3):

This isn't really an answer I don't think, just a question. Why would you bring in a 3rd party `http` mock `service`, when angular has `$httpBackend` built in? If it was a conscious decision, what made you go for it?

Comment: Because I would like to mock the data service behavior since I'm testing the controller. The controller has a dependency on the data service, and not in $http. When I need to test the data service, which has a dependency on $http, that's when I'll use $httpBackend